# How to work with security tokens with Progress OpenEdge 11.7.3 HTTP Client

Tags: httpclient, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with HTTP Client feature for Progress OpenEdge.
Basic calls without any security work just fine.
I need to make the calls with security tokens.
I've never done this before.

Can anyone help me with how to setup the iHttpRequest object with the security token.

```
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.IHttpRequest.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.IHttpResponse.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.ClientBuilder.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.RequestBuilder.

DEFINE VARIABLE oRequest  AS IHttpRequest  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE oResponse AS IHttpResponse NO-UNDO.

oRequest = RequestBuilder:GET( "https://xyz" )
                         :REQUEST.

oResponse = ClientBuilder:Build()
                         :Client
                         :Execute(oRequest).
```

Comment: What kind of security tokens? Do you just need OAuth headers to be passed or something else?

Comment: Sorry I took so long. It's been hectic. I've figured it out though. It ended up being normal headers that needed to be added:.......:AddHeader("security token key goes here", "your token goes here" ).... NOT the BasicAuthentication method or credentials one.  Being the first time I'm working with this I struggled a little figuring out exactly how it is supposed to be.